# Why does My Canon Rebel T3i/600D take multiple shots after beeping for two seconds every time I press the shutter button?

Tags: troubleshooting

For some reason every time I press the shutter button to take a picture on my Cannon Rebel Ti3 600d it beeps for a few second and takes many pictures. I though this was the auto exposure bracket feature which I used earlier but it is turned off. I also have the single shot mode on. So why is is doing this?

Comment: Usually that is the Custom Self-Timer but you said you are in single-shot mode, so could it be overridden by a User or Scene mode? Try it in Program (P) and see if it still happens.

Comment: Yea it still happens in Program mode.

Comment: for debugging purposes, a photo of your display with the settings would be helpful perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have set the self timer to be active and to also take bracketed shots. Note that shots can be bracketed in terms of white-balance fine tuning as well as in terms of exposure, so check the setting in the menu under WB fine tuning to see if bracketing is turned on there. If you have exposure bracketing or WB bracketing enabled the camera will take three shots with the self-timer even when the Drive mode is set to single shot. If both auto exposure bracketing and WB bracketing are enabled you will get nine shots at once.

Comment: Very good answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I went into the settings and both the WB and Exposure bracketing are off. Is there any way it is being overridden?